# Angularjs with Coffeescript class

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I was trying angularjs with Coffescript class

I was able to inject and able to do a successful example using coffeescript. But to access $scope I have to write functions within the constructor. What I can do to get it out of it. If there is another good way to write that please let me know.

Here is my working coffeescript code

```
class PersonCtrl
    @$inject = ['$scope']

    constructor: (@scope) ->
        @scope.persons = [
            firstName:"Kunjan"
            lastName:"Dalal"
        ,
            firstName:"Kunj"
            lastName:"Dalal"
        ]

        @scope.addPerson = () =>
            @scope.persons.push angular.copy @scope.person
```

Please let me know if any further details required.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have used the following syntax:

```
app = angular.module 'myapp', []

class MySimpleCtrl

  @$inject: ['$scope'] 
  constructor: (@scope) ->
    @scope.demo = 'demo value'
    @scope.clearText = @clearText

  clearText: =>
    @scope.demo = ""

app.controller 'MySimpleCtrl', MySimpleCtrl

angular.bootstrap document, ['myapp']
```

Take a look at this jsFiddle:
     http://jsfiddle.net/jwcMA/

**UPDATE**
@oto-brglez the .bootstrap() call replaces having ng-app on your `<html>` tag

**UPDATE**
@TylerCollier, this was a while back, now I would probably use the *Controller As* notation (or maybe TypeScript!)

COFFEE

```
class PetController 
    constructor: (@$scope) ->
        @pets = ['Fido','Felix']
    addPet: (pet) ->
        @pets.push(pet)
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="PetController as pc">
...
<li ng-repeat="pet in pc.pets">
```

Comment: Okies, So, I was missing registering of scope in constructor. Thanks that thing make sense at least for javascript.

Comment: @malix could you please explain the propose of last line?

Comment: For each method you want to add, you have to also map it in the constructor? `@scope.clearText = @clearText`

Comment: @TylerCollier, this was a while back, now I would probably use the *Controller As* notation, or better yet, TypeScript :)